# Is there a free-standing equivalent to PowerPoint's "SmartArt" feature?

Tags: linux, images, presentation, text-processing

MS PowerPoint includes [a feature called "SmartArt"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SmartArt#SmartArt). It provides a means of automating various kinds of graphical layouts of lists. I believe it was introduced with [MS Office 2007](http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/powerpoint101/ig/PowerPoint-2007-Ribbon/05insert_ribbon_smartart.htm).

I'm not a Windows user, and in the flavours of Linux I have on my machines (Ubuntu and Mint) I use LibreOffice. At the moment, this feature is [not available in Impress](https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37932), and my hunch is that it's unlikely to show up any time soon.

So my (simple) question: is there an independent application that can do what SmartArt does (automate different graphical layouts of lists), and in particular which run on Linux?

Comment: By any chance, have you ever found anything? Currently looking for a solution and the closest thing I can find is graphviz, which, while hugely more flexible, doesn't provide nearly the ease-of-use of MS Office SmartArt.

Comment: @kdb No I haven't, I'm afraid. I see that there is now a comment (#16) in that enhancement request [giving a couple extension suggestions](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37932#c16), which also notes that they "aren't really full SmartArt replacements". HTH.

Comment: I tried both, and, sadly, the note is quite on point. The "smart" extension is more a proof of concept, that requires a lot of manual adjustments, and the "template collection" is just a collection of fixed-layout templates, i.e. no automatic creation from input is performed at all.

Comment: Consider using LaTeX (e.g. [PDFbeamer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfbeamer/)...) perhaps with advi or hevea

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, whether or not SmartArt is included, but as [some screenshots looks promising](https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&tbm=isch&q=%22wps+office%22+smartart&oq=%22wps+office%22+smartart) - did you ever try [WPS Office](https://www.wps.com/)?